# What Password do you Use When you're Installing Software on a Virtual Machine running 13.04?

Tags: installation, 13.04, virtualbox, password, root

I am using Windows 8 and through virtualbox I am running 13.04 and it would be just great if I could actually use it for what I wanted it: installing and running GNU Octave. I can't seem to because when I attempt to install in the software centre I am missing one vital thing: a password.

I downloaded it from [here](http://virtualboximages.com/Ubuntu+GNOME+13.04+amd64+Virtual+Appliance)

Comment: You mean the root password?

Comment: I do believe so, yes. But anything that will work for the software centre will do.

Comment: That would be the password which you would have chosen while installing Ubuntu in the VM...

Comment: I didn't use any... I downloaded a file for 13.04 AMD64 @ virtualboximages.com Extracted the rar file and then I ran the virtual machine provided and it didn't at any time require a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password which you are looking for is `adminuser` as mentioned [here](http://virtualboximages.com/Ubuntu+GNOME+13.04+amd64+Virtual+Appliance)